# Native chrome datepicker. Six characters in year field

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, datepicker

How can i limit a number of characters, that allowed in chrome datepicker year field? Fiddle of problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/L2r3wvt8/

```
<input type="date" value="201223-01-01">
```

(value is set for example, problem is - **if user types a year value, it's not restarting after 4 symbols, but after 6**)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Browsers have no reasons to limit the year field to 4 digits by default.  You should specify max attribute.

```
<input type="date" max="9999-12-31">
```